# ObjectiveC saving images in tableview

Tags: plist, jpeg, tableview

I currently have a tableView that the user can populate with data- both text and an image.

When the app exits I save all the text in to a plist file as always.
All the images are saved as 0, 1 ,2, 3, 4 dot jpg but the problem is that when I delete one row I can't take for granted that the indexpath.row . jpg is the correct image because it changes.

So the question is - how is the best way to save the images?

Thanks

Comment: Not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep an array of "image names" in your table view datasource and save this along with the  text as plist file (so you get images.plist and text.plist). when you remove rows, you remove the image name from your images.plist and the related text in the text.plist.

A nice way to store data and show it in table views is CoreData. While it seems a bit too much for now, it's worth to work with it:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html